# Reading From an Array within an Array in Dataweave

Tags: dataweave

I am trying to create an output JSON Array object from a JSON source with subarrays within the parent Array object and not able to figure the right dataweave to traverse the subarray. The target JSON array should be repeating elements from source subarray ExpenseReportDetailArray. Here is the source JSON Array with the subarray:

```json
[
    {
        "ExpenseReportHeader": {
            "ReportName": "Jane Zoe ExpensesX"
        },
        "ExpenseReportDetailArray": [
            {
                "CityStart": "CLT",
                "CityEnd": "AUS"
            },
            {
                "CityStart": "AUS",
                "CityEnd": "CLT"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ExpenseReportHeader": {
            "ReportName": "Jane Zoe ExpensesY"
        },
        "ExpenseReportDetailArray": [{
            "CityStart": "CLT",
            "CityEnd": "AUS"
        }]
    }
]
```

Here is the target JSON Array:

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "from source X",
        "SourceCity": "from source ExpenseReportDetailArray[x]",
        "DestinationCity": "from source ExpenseReportDetailArray[x]",
    },
    {
        "Name": "from source",
        "SourceCity": "from source ExpenseReportDetailArray[x+1]",
        "DestinationCity": "from source ExpenseReportDetailArray[x+1]",
    },
    {
        "Name": "from source Y",
        "SourceCity": "from source ExpenseReportDetailArray[y",
        "DestinationCity": "from source ExpenseReportDetailArray[y]",
    }
]
```

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
    Name: payload01.ExpenseReportHeader.ReportName,
    payload01 map () -> {
        SourceCity: payload01.ExpenseReportDetailArray.CityStart,
        DestinationCity: payload01.ExpenseReportDetailArray.CityEnd
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide an expected output with values, in addition to the conceptual one you shared. That way we can figure if a solution is going to be valid to you. Also note that using the code block you should remove the extra single quotes from the samples.

Comment: The input JSON has extra commas after the last keys of each object. Those should be removed to make it a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flatMap() to avoid nesting arrays. Then map each record in the child arrays and insert the name from the parent there. I'm using a JSON output for clarity. You can change it back to Java:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload flatMap (( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> 
        payload01.ExpenseReportDetailArray map  {
            Name: payload01.ExpenseReportHeader.ReportName,
            SourceCity: $.CityStart,
            DestinationCity: $.CityEnd
        }
)
```

Output (after removing extra commas in the input):

```json
[
  {
    "Name": "Jane Zoe ExpensesX",
    "SourceCity": "CLT",
    "DestinationCity": "AUS"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jane Zoe ExpensesX",
    "SourceCity": "AUS",
    "DestinationCity": "CLT"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jane Zoe ExpensesY",
    "SourceCity": "CLT",
    "DestinationCity": "AUS"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is an option which will help you.
Input

```
[
  {
    "ExpenseReportHeader": {
      "ReportName": "Jane Zoe ExpensesX"
    },
    "ExpenseReportDetailArray": [
      {
        "CityStart": "CLT",
        "CityEnd": "AUS"
      },
      {
        "CityStart": "AUS",
        "CityEnd": "CLT"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ExpenseReportHeader": {
      "ReportName": "Jane Zoe ExpensesY"
    },
    "ExpenseReportDetailArray": [
      {
        "CityStart": "CLT",
        "CityEnd": "AUS"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Dataweave Script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload flatMap (report, index) -> {
    Name: if (report.ExpenseReportHeader.ReportName != null) "from source " ++ report.ExpenseReportHeader.ReportName else "from source",
    SourceCity: report.ExpenseReportDetailArray[0].CityStart,
    DestinationCity: report.ExpenseReportDetailArray[-1].CityEnd
}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "from source Jane Zoe ExpensesX",
    "SourceCity": "CLT",
    "DestinationCity": "CLT"
  },
  {
    "Name": "from source Jane Zoe ExpensesY",
    "SourceCity": "CLT",
    "DestinationCity": "AUS"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

there is another option by using Flatten

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten(payload map ((item, index) -> item.ExpenseReportDetailArray map {
    "Name": item.ExpenseReportHeader.ReportName,
    "SourceCity": $.CityStart,
    "DestinationCity": $.CityEnd
}))
```

and output is as below:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Jane Zoe ExpensesX",
    "SourceCity": "CLT",
    "DestinationCity": "AUS"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jane Zoe ExpensesX",
    "SourceCity": "AUS",
    "DestinationCity": "CLT"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jane Zoe ExpensesY",
    "SourceCity": "CLT",
    "DestinationCity": "AUS"
  }
]
```

below is the DataWeave Playground screen shot

[image]